# How to rollup multiple directories separately with one output

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs, transpiler

So, I have a directory:

```
mods/
-core/
--index.js
--scripts/
---lots of stuff imported by core/index
```

This works with typical rollup fashion if you want to rollup to for example `mods/core/index.min.js`

But I have many of these `mods/**/` directories and I want to take advantage of the fact that they are rollup'd into iifes. Each `mods/**/index.js` will, rather than `export`, assign to a global variable that we presume is provided:

`mods/core/index.js`

```
import ui from './scripts/ui/'
global.ui = ui
```

`mods/someMod/scripts/moddedClass.js`

```
export default class moddedClass extends global.ui.something { /* some functionality extension */}
```

`mods/someMod/index.js`

```
import moddedClass from './scripts/moddedClass'
global.ui.something = moddedClass
```

So hopefully you can see how each mod directory can be rollup'd in typical fashion but, I need to then put the actual iifes inside another one so that:

`mods/compiled.js`

```
(function compiled() {
  const global = {};

  (function core() {
    //typical rollup iife
  })();

  (function someMod() {
    //typical rollup iife
  })();

  //a footer like return global or global.init()
})();
```

Any help towards this end would be greatly appreciated. The simplest possible answer, I think, is how I can simply get a string value for each mod's iife instead of rollup writing it to a file.

At that point I could just iterate the `/mods/` directory, in an order specified by some `modlist.json` or something, and call rollup on each `/mod/index.js`, then build the outer iife myself from strings.

However, I suppose this would not be a full solution for sourcemapping? Or can multiple inline sourcemaps be included? With source mapping in mind, I wonder if another build step might be necessary, where each mod is transpiled before this system even gets to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use rollup's bundle.generate api to generate multiple iifes and write them into one file using fs.appendFile.

For the sourcemaps you can use this module（it's from the same author of rollup) https://github.com/rich-harris/sorcery

Comment: Hey thank you for this, at least a step in the right direction. Do you think you could explain it as if I am an idiot, though? Some basic code example maybe? I'm just having some trouble putting the whole picture together

Comment: @DanieClawson I think rollup's wiki is a good start, https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/JavaScript-API, you can refer to the code example in the wiki, the code is simple if you have the right direction.

Comment: Well the rollup end is quite clear now, yes. I am stuck on understanding what I need to give to sorcery, so that I get the proper final output.

Specifically, sorcery says it follows the "chain" of sourcemaps back to the root. The issue being, that implies to me I would have to create a sourcemap from individual mod iifes -> big iife, somehow.

Comment: Okay so I have generated that, but I can't figure out how to use sorcery without generating actual intermediate files for the build steps, and just use strings like I showed. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the way I ended up solving this was using [`source-map-concat`](https://github.com/lydell/source-map-concat)

It basically does what I described, right out of the box. The only thing I had to do was to *asynchronously* iterate the mod directory and rollup each mod, before passing the results to `source-map-concat`, since `rollup.rollup` returns a Promise.

I also ended up wanting in-line sourcemaps so that the code can be directly injected rather than written to a file, so I used [`convert-source-map`](https://github.com/thlorenz/convert-source-map) for that.

The only issue left to solve is sub-source mapping. Sorcery would work great for that, if I was generating files, but I would like to keep it as string sources. For now it will at least show me what mod an error came from, but not the sub-file it came from. If anyone has info on how to do a sorcery-style operation on strings let me know.

Here's the relevant final code from my file:

```
const rollup  = require("rollup")
const concat  = require("source-map-concat")
const convert = require("convert-source-map")

const fs   = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const modsPath = path.join(__dirname, "mods")

const getNames = _ => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(modsPath, "loadList.json"), "utf8"))

const wrap = (node, mod) => {
  node.prepend("\n// File: " + mod.source + "\n")
}

const rolls = {}
const bundles = {}

const rollupMod = (modName, after) => {
  let dir = path.join(modsPath, modName),
      file = path.join(dir, "index.js")

  rollup.rollup({
    entry: file,
    external: "G",
    plugins: []
  }).then(bundle => {
    rolls[modName] = bundle.generate({
      format: "iife",
      moduleName: modName,
      exports: "none",
      useStrict: false,
      sourceMap: true
    })

    after()
  })
}

const rollupMods = after => {
  let names = getNames(), i = 0,
      rollNext = _ => rollupMod(names[i++], _ => i < names.length - 1? rollNext() : after())

  rollNext()
}

const bundleCode = after => {
  rollupMods(_ => {
    let mods = concat(getNames().map(modName => {
      let mod = rolls[modName]

      return {
        source: path.join(modsPath, modName),
        code: mod.code,
        map: mod.map
      }
    }), {
      delimiter: "\n",
      process: wrap
    })

    mods.prepend("(function(){\n")
    mods.add("\n})();")

    let result = mods.toStringWithSourceMap({
      file: path.basename('.')
    })

    bundles.code = result.code + "\n" + convert.fromObject(result.map).toComment()

    after(bundles.code)
  })
}

exports.bundleCode = bundleCode
```